# Object not set to the instance of an Object ERROR Excel 2013 Automation VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, automation

Trying to create a small report program in VB.Net. It works in Excel 2003 and 2010, but throws an error in Excel 2013 when trying to create the second worksheet. The Procedure is listed below, I also point out the line where it errors. It doesn't even catch in the Try and Catch that I added it comes across as an "Unhandled Exception".

The target framework is 3.5

Have tried x86, x64, and Any CPU as the target CPU

I used the 2003 and 2010 .dlls as my reference.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub DRpts()
    Try
        Dim strFileDirName As String = ""
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor


        'Morning Report Sheet 1
        Dim MornRpt As String = "SELECT DateCreated, ReportClass, SUM(QtyOrdered),          SUM(ExtendedPrice) " & _
        "FROM tmp_DailyReport GROUP BY DateCreated, ReportClass"

        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet1 As Object
        Dim oSheet2 As Object

        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add
        oSheet1 = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        oSheet1.Name = "Morning Report"

        'Load Headers
        oSheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Class"
        oSheet1.Range("B1").Value = "Units"
        oSheet1.Range("C1").Value = "Extended Price"

        'Formatting()
        oSheet1.Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True

        Dim CellLoc As String = ""
        Dim CellCntr As Integer = 2
        Dim SRptDate As String = Me.RptStart.Text
        Dim ERptDate As String = Me.RptEnd.Text

        Dim Reader1 As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
        Using connection As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=#########;")
            Dim Command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(MornRpt, connection)
            Command.Connection.Open()
            Reader1 = Command.ExecuteReader
            While Reader1.Read()
                CellLoc = "A" & CellCntr
                oSheet1.Range(CellLoc).Value = Reader1.GetValue(1).ToString
                CellLoc = "B" & CellCntr
                oSheet1.Range(CellLoc).Value = Reader1.GetValue(2).ToString
                CellLoc = "C" & CellCntr
                oSheet1.Range(CellLoc).Value = Reader1.GetValue(3).ToString
                CellCntr = CellCntr + 1
            End While
        End Using

        Dim FormatRange As String = "C2:C" & CellCntr
        oSheet1.Range(FormatRange).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        oSheet1.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        oSheet1.Columns("A").HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft

        ------>   oSheet2 = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")   *** BAD INDEX ERROR OCCURS HERE *** <------------------
        ------>   ' Also tried this variation --> *** oSheet2 = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ***  Neither Work

        oSheet2.Name = "Summary"
        Dim OverseasSales As String = "SELECT SUM(QtyOrdered) AS Units, SUM(ExtendedPrice) AS ExtPrice " & _
        "FROM dbo.tmp_DailyReport " & _
        "WHERE (CustomerNo BETWEEN '0' AND '9)' OR " & _
        "CustomerNo BETWEEN '0' AND '9' OR " & _
        "CustomerNo = '######')" & _
        "GROUP BY DateCreated "

        'Load(Headers)
        oSheet2.Range("A1").Value = "Report Class"
        oSheet2.Range("B1").Value = "Product"
        oSheet2.Range("C1").Value = "Units"
        oSheet2.Range("D1").Value = "ExtendedPrice"
```

This is the error that I receive.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GoldenManagement.DailyReport.DRpts()
   at GoldenManagement.DailyReport.RunDailyRpt2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that i posted this. I Found the solution sometime ago.

Where the error was occurring I should have used;

```
oSheet2 = CType(Me.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
oSheet2.Name = "Sheet2"
```

The newer versions of office will default to one sheet in the book unless specified.